# Powershell script for youtube-dl

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I'm trying to write a script to simplify input of variables to `youtube-dl`.

Here is my `ffmpeg` command (replace items in brackets):

```
./ffmpeg -ss ['starting time', ex: 05:49] -i $(./youtube-dl -f 22 --get-url ['video youtube url']) -t ['clip duration in seconds'] -c:v copy -c:a copy ['file result name'].mp4
```

Here is my PowerShell command:

```
cls

$url = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the Youtube Video URL"

$start = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the video start time (H:MM:SS)"

$end = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the clip duration in seconds"

$name = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the video name"

./ffmpeg -ss $start -i $(./youtube-dl -f 22 --get-url $url) -t $end -c:v copy -c:a copy $name.mp4
```

**And this is the result I receive from Powershell**:

[image: Powershell screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that the output of youtube-dl is the filename and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 - Powershell-script - Download KRIEGSTANZARCHIV as mp3 (example youtube-playlist : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLX4Ev6XiBJn1VHyPfnq74Gst4PmVtpZKX (full automatic):

https://pastebin.com/3uFYPBkW

```
    # Download following youtube-playlist : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLX4Ev6XiBJn1VHyPfnq74Gst4PmVtpZKX
    # as mp3
    # Note : ffmpeg and youtube-dl have to be installed before this will work!!!

    # this is one line here!!! ... save as Load-KRIEGSTANZARCHIV.ps1 for example
    youtube-dl.exe -x -i -w --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.complaylist?list=PLX4Ev6XiBJn1VHyPfnq74Gst4PmVtpZKX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the link in a variable in PowerShell:

```
$yt_link = Read-Host
```

With this statement you can both navigate to the right directory and execute the `youtube-dl` command neccesary to download videos.

```
cmd.exe /c cd <Path where youtube-dl.exe is stored> "&"  youtube-dl $yt_link
```

It's important that you use `"&"` because the raw & sign will cause an error because that character is reserved by PowerShell.

Comment: Why are you proxying the call to `youtube-dl.exe` through CMD? This is completely unnecessary. `cd $ytdlpath; ./youtube-dl.exe $yt_link` would do the same thing without having to resort to a CMD workaround.